# Do you have to use DockerHub with Spring Cloud Data Flow to use Python

Tags: java, python, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've been following along https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/polyglot/processor/

It looks like it requires dockerhub in order to use python with spring cloud data flow. Is it possible to run a polyglot application without dockerhub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still run your polyglot app without docker. There are out of the box apps available to support running python script as a processor app.

- Using [Jython Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Einstein.SR6/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-python-jython-processor)
- Using [Scriptable Transform Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Einstein.SR6/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-modules-scriptable-transform)

But, remember that when using these out-of-box apps you **don't** have to write any python code to produce/consume messages from the messaging platform (Kafka etc.,). It is taken care by the binder you choose on these apps. That is a fundamental **difference** between what you saw from the docker based recipe(which needs you to write explicit code to produce/consume data to/from Kafka) and the above out of the box python processors.